# Why am I geting a blank when I run this string funtion in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

So I was solving a problem that required me to put unique characters in a string without using a data structure.

```
fun main(){
    val s1 = "fhfnfnfjuw"
    val s2 = "Osayuki"
    val s3 = "Raymond"
    val s4 = "Aseosa"

  uniqueChar(s1)
}


fun uniqueChar(s: String){
    val updatedString = ""
    s.forEach {c ->
        if (!updatedString.contains(c)){
            updatedString.plus(c)
        }
    }
    println(updatedString)

}
```

And getting this error
[image]

I'm not sure what's going on and why I'm getting a blank. I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't see it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For those of us who don't have a magnifying glass to hand (along with those who use screen readers, or mobile devices, &c), could you [post the error as text instead of an image](/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) please?

Comment: fyi `process finished with exit code 0` isn't an error - lots of command-line stuff returns an exit code, and `0` usually means success. So nothing's going wrong in your script, it's just not doing what you expect it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updatedString.plus(c)` does not change `updatedString`.  It creates a new string, including the character `c`.  Since you don't do anything with that, the new string goes...nowhere.

Instead, you probably wanted `updatedString = updatedString.plus(c)` -- or something better with `StringBuilder`, but that's the closest version to *your* code.

Comment: Got you, that makes sense. It ended up working for me. I appreciate the help.